# Yii2 : Something Which works in Backend doesn't work on frontend

Tags: php, css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2-advanced-app. I'm using some widgets like `'kartik\date\DatePicker', 'wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget'` in my project.

They are working well with my backend. But if I use the same code with frontend, they doesn't work. Suppose I clicked on date to choose one, it shows the datepicker(If I am using it with backend code), it looks like this:

[image: datepicker])

but if I'm using the same on frontend side, it doesn't work. That is, nothing happens after clicking on datepicker in frontend.

Why it doesn't work? The same is happening with `wbraganca dynamic form`.

*Please note that I'm using a custom theme/template in my frontend.*

My '_form.php' in backend is as follows -

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
<?=  $form-> field($model, 'ven_established_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [

        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Established date...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-M-dd'
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

And, the same in frontend is as follows -

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
<?=  $form-> field($model, 'ven_established_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [

        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Established date...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-M-dd'
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

Still it works in backend but not in frontend....

Comment: show both the views (backend and frontend) where you use the datepicker

Comment: Did you have some javascript error? check the console

Comment: No, it doesn't show any error; but no any action is not performed on clicking.

Comment: Have you configured the widgets in `backend/config`, `frontend/config` or `common/config` ?

Comment: how should I configure?

Comment: Have you properly setup assets manager on your frontend app ?

Comment: Please tell me the names of js files required for datepicker, so that I will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in you $form
Form [kartik](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker):

> NOTE: This extension depends on the yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap extension. Check the composer.json for this extension's requirements and dependencies that may be updated by composer.

To solve it use right Active form

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
// replace this in your view
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
```